# How to make a Symbol-Button with 16x16 pixel icon-size?

Tags: windows, mfc

I tried to make a Symbol Button with MFC. The Icon-Resource (*.ico) has a size of 16x16 pixels. When I load the icon into the button, the icon appears twice as large. Do you know how I can specify the size of the icon drawn onto the button-surface?

The Code Fragment I'm using:

```
CButton* btn = reinterpret_cast<CButton*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON_RUNTER));
btn->SetIcon(AfxGetApp()->LoadIconA(MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_RUNTER)));
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LoadImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648045%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of `LoadIcon` which will allow you to specify the size.